# "autoreconf": include/Makefile.in not found

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, makefile, compiler-errors

I'm have download this [tarball](http://libtheoraplayer.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/libtheoraplayer/trunk/) that I want to compile. So I have written this:

```
/tmp/libtheoraplayer/trunk/$ autoreconf --force --install
```

but I'm gettin this:

`` libtoolize: Consider adding `AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])' to
configure.ac and libtoolize: rerunning libtoolize, to keep the correct
libtool macros in-tree. libtoolize: Consider adding `-I m4' to
ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS in Makefile.am. configure.ac:54: required file
**`include/Makefile.in'** not found autoreconf: automake failed with exit
status: 1 ``

But the file Makefile.in is in the `src/` folder..

Any idea?

Javier

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, end users who install programs need not do autoreconf. It is for developers. When you have code from a repository, and try to build it (even if you are not a developer), you need to autoreconf.
If this is not the case, you only try to install and use the software, try creating a fresh copy, and

```
./configure
make
make install
```

HTH

Comment: In the second case, you receive a tarball from the developers (you do not download code from a repository using SVN or some other source control software), which comes with a configure script. You need not even autoconf, autmake installed in your system (therefore cannot call autoreconf) to be able to compile (build) the software.

Comment: This is correct. If the developer makes tarballs using `make dist` (or better yet, `make distcheck`), the timestamps on the various inputs to the autotools will be set up so that it won't try to run `autoconf`, `automake`, &c. when it's unpacked.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, If at all you need autoreconf, install it

```
yum install automake autoconf
```